# jquery fading in on screen after time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Hi guys iam trying to figure out how i can get an image to appear onto the screen after a certain amount of time , after the animation has started.

So i got an image and i have used css to place it where i want it to be.

```
#laser
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 650px;
}
```

Dose anyone know how i can possibly get that image not to appear when the animation starts but to appear after 3 seconds in that certain place where i have used css to place it?

Edit: This is the code i got so far.

```
<div id="laser">
  <img src="images/laser.png" alt="laser">
</div>

#laser
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 650px;
   display: none;
}
```

Then i just used the code that you gave me. But it just stop everything else from working.

```
$('#laser').animate({
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px'
}, 3000, function() {
    $(this).show('slow');
});​
```

Link to my code if u want to look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/wdy5P/5/

Comment: Try JQuery setTimeOut() function.

Comment: Any luck with this? There are no images on the fiddle so cant tell if anything works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.animate()` method.. After the specified duration the code in the callback will be executed..

```
$('#laser').animate({
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px'
}, 3000, function() {
    $(this).show('slow');
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wdy5P/2/)**

Comment: Isn't the 3000 in animate() the period how long will the animation last ?

Comment: Hmm i tried this but for some reason that refuses 2 work just stop my whole animation.

Comment: What is .pan() in the code.. If that is a plugin method , the page will throw errors unless we add the plugin resource

Comment: OMG lol. i had the library jquery-1.3.2.min.js I should have used I should have used jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Comment: @AliIssa - No, you should have used 1.8 or newer by now, 1.4 was years ago ?

Comment: oh ok so what should it be? could u get me the source would be great

Comment: @AliIssa ..  Glad to have helped :

Answer (score 2):

Adding a single millisecond to `show()` makes it an animation (invisible to the eye but added to the FX queue), and in turn lets you use the `delay()` function to delay the image being shown by 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds):

```
$('#laser').delay(3000).show(1);
```

The image would of course have to be initially `display: none;`

Comment: I tried that. Display none will take out completely. But that java code wont work for me